# Process of e-sign live api integration

Tags: electronic-signature

Can somebody suggest me how to integrate e-sign live to my web app ? After integrating, what are the things that the API will handle and what are the things that it expects me to provide to work appropriately ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a very broad question.  Trying to be as concise as possible your app would probably need to have the following list of things:

1) documents to be signed
2) who is signing
3) where the signatures and form fields go

The eSignature service would handle the workflow, rendering of the documents and most importantly the audit log making it legally binding that the transaction actually happened. I work for DocuSign so I am very familiar with that eSignature solution.  You can get started with DocuSign API on www.docusign.com/devcenter

Let me know if you have other questions.

-mb